# SQL combining two tables of which two columns have the same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I basically have 2 tables like this:

```
Table 1: -name-    -time-  
          one       9pm
          two       8pm
          three     7pm



Table 2: -name-    -time-   -value-
          one       9pm        1
          two       8pm        2
```

And I want to know what kind of query I need to use to get table 3 as output (I use postgreSQL).

```
Table 3: -name-    -time-   -value-
          one       9pm        1
          two       8pm        2
          three     7pm       null
```

Any help would be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple left join with two `AND`ed conditions in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT t1."-name-",
       t1."-time-",
       t2."-value-"
       FROM "Table 1" t1
            LEFT JOIN "Table 2" t2
                      ON t2."-name-" = t1."-name-"
                         AND t2."-time-" = t1."-time-";
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a right join
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp

This goes over how to do one.  It also has other types of joins.

Comment: Oh yeah right! I learned this a long time ago, should have remembered that.. Thank you!

Comment: @PRYDAX thanks for say that helped. Though you might be new to programming so I linked to that site so you could learn more.   I see people have been down marking my answer.... odd when it answered the person asking question